# Python Print Table for Term and Definition with Handled Overflow

Tags: python-3.x, csv, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a program that prints out a two column table (Term and Definition) something like this: (table width should be 80 characters)

```
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                  Term                |              Definition            
    |
    +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    |       this is the first term.        |This is the definition for thefirst| 
    |                                      |term that wraps around because the |
    |                                      |definition is longer than the width|
    |                                      |of the column.                     |
    +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
    |The term may also be longer than the  |This is the definition for the     |
    |width of the column and should wrap   |second term.                       |
    |around as well.                       |                                   |
    +--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I have existing code for this, but it prints out "this is the first term" on every line because I have used a nested for loop. (Also tried implementing the textwrap module) Here is the code that I have:

```
# read file
with open(setsList[selectedSet-1], "r", newline="") as setFile:
    cardList = list(csv.reader(setFile))
    setFile.close()

for i in range(len(cardList)):
    wrapped_term = textwrap.wrap(cardList[i][0], 30)
    wrapped_definition = textwrap.wrap(cardList[i][1], 30)

    for line in wrapped_term:
        for line2 in wrapped_definition:
            print(line, "                              ",line2)
        print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of (trial) & error & random youtube videos, the solution: (if anyone has a similar problem)

```
with open("table.csv", "r", newline="") as setFile:
cardList = list(csv.reader(setFile))
setFile.close()

print("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+")
print("|                Term                  |               Definition              |")
print("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+")
print()



for x in range(len(cardList)):

wrapped_term = textwrap.wrap(cardList[x][0], 30)
wrapped_definition = textwrap.wrap(cardList[x][1], 30)

wrapped_list = []


for i in range(len(wrapped_term)):
    try:
        wrapped_list.append([wrapped_term[i], wrapped_definition[i]])

    except IndexError:

        if len(wrapped_term) > len(wrapped_definition):

            wrapped_list.append([wrapped_term[i], ""])

        elif len(wrapped_term) < len(wrapped_definition):

            wrapped_list.append(["", wrapped_definition[i]])

column1 = len("               Term                ")
column2 = len("              Definition            ")


print("+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+")
for item in wrapped_list:
    print("|", item[0], " "*(column1 - len(item[0])),"|", item[1], " "*(column2-len(item[1])), "|")
print("+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+")
print("*                                                                              *")
```

Basically, I created a wrapped version of each of my terms and definitions.

Then the try-catch stuff checks whether the term is longer than the definition (in terms of lines) and if so puts blank lines for the definition and vice versa.

I then created a wrapped_list (combined terms and definitions) to store this the above.

With help from this video: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9BRuhqEb2Q), I formatted the table.

Hope this helped anyone struggling with a similar problem - this can be applied to any number of columns in a table, and any length of csv file.